# Error Handler: Bash starter script for Python endless loop

Tags: python, bash, event-handling

I have a project that requires an endless loop that I wrote in Python.  This scrip will loop through an array of variables (Created once at the beginning of the script) perform a task using each one, and start over.  This works fine 99.9% of the time, but every once in a while the electrons get stuck and it crashes.  THIS IS NOT AN ISSUE, and is caused by hardware constraints not my script.  The error my Python scrip outputs is as follows, and is caused if my Arduino on the other side of the I2C bus is busy doing something else and unable to respond:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i2cGet.py", line 105, in <module>
    i2c.i2cWrite(0x54, 1, fanCurrent)
  File "/home/pi/arduino_Interface/i2c.py", line 43, in i2cWrite
    bus.write_byte(address,data)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

To take care of this, I have a bash "starter" that will restart the python script when it does crash using `until python script.py do`.  This also works just fine, but I am working on my event logging for this process, and need a way of knowing which variable in the array my python script crashed on so I can insert it into the log.  Presumably this would be done with a custom event handler in Python, but I am having a hard time figuring out what needs to be done to accomplish this task.

The question in summary: How do I create a custom event handler in Python, and then retrieve the event for use in my bash starter script?

Please excuse my terminology for event/event handler.  I am simply looking for a way, in the event of an error, pass the last element in the array I was working with.  In this case the 0x54 that is in the i2cWrite function, but it may not always be listed there if the script crashes somewhere else in the loop.  Perhaps the more correct term is error handler, not event handler...

At this point, the only reason I am doing this in Bash is I had a starter script i used for persistence in a previous project that worked well, and it was easy to adapt it to fit this project.  If it is easier to handle this with a Python starter, I can easily (I think) port this over.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say crash, is that with an exception?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "event handler" and "event"? I can't think of any normal meaning of those terms that makes any sense here?

Comment: Meanwhile, where does Python get the array from? Do you have any persistence mechanism you're already using?

Comment: Finally, is there a reason you have to do this in bash instead of in Python? You could, e.g., use `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures` to kick off one worker servicing a queue, and whenever the worker crashes (whatever that actually means), the parent will see that job will fail and you can just retry it.

Comment: Updating now.. Check back in a minute.

Comment: Question updated... Hopefully it answers your questions..

Answer (score 0):

```
until event=$(python script.py)
do
  ...
done
```

The python script should print the event to stdout, and you can then refer to `$event` in the body of the loop.

Comment: This won't pass the element in the array that I was working with when the python script crashed.  This element is what I am looking to pass back.

Comment: I thought your question was about how to get it into bash. I assumed you knew how to get the relevant element in python.

Comment: I need to get the element that I am working with in python to be passed to the bash starter script when the python script crashes. I have the bash starter script with an until loop, and the python script doing what needs to be done, I just need to know what element Python is working with when it crashes.

Comment: I don't know python. And you haven't posted any details of your python script, so how do you expect anyone to answer that part?

Comment: It may just be my ignorance, but I don't see how what my python script is doing is relevant.  I just need to pass a variable back when the python script crashes...

Comment: The error handler should print the variable, and my answer shows how to get that into a bash variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30870/discussion-between-tar-gz-and-barmar)